# Selected joining of lines

Tags: python, selected

I am very new with python and I need to solve the following (by hand or by python):
for a dataset, where each file consists of undefined-groups of lines of a varying number of numbers, followed by one line of text incl. dates and numbers (sorry if the sentence doesn't make sence):

```
2,

4,

6,

1,

2,

02-sep-2016, blah blah, blah, 83838338

3,

0,

0,

03-Aug-2000, blah, 300033
```

I need the highest number above the line of text to be in front of the text and the rest to be deleted:

```
6,02-sep-2016, blah blah, blah, 83838338

3,03-Aug-2000, blah, 300033
```

I know the `max()` function, but how do I specify as a general rule for all my files which numbers to include, and how can I selectively turn some numbers into an `int()` without including the sentence? 
I tried an `if` statement with `len(line)<=3` and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your input file using `for line in my_file: ...`. If the lines you want to use `max` on always follow the format you described (a number followed by a comma and then a carriage return), you can store them in a set as integers by discarding the comma and the `\n` using a slice and then transtyping the result (i.e. using `int(line[:-2])`). `max` then gives you the largest element of the set, which you can convert back to a string with `str()`. To distinguish between those lines and the ones that feature a date, look for something you only find in date lines (i.e. characters or -).

Answer (score 0):

```
from future.utils import isint
data = ["02-sep-2016, blah blah, blah, 83838338",2, 4,6,1,2,"02-sep-2016, blah blah, blah, 83838338",3,0,0,"03-Aug-2000, blah, 300033"]

vals=[]
final_data = "%d,%s"
formatted_rec = []
for each_val in data:

    if not isint(each_val) and "-" in each_val:
        if vals:
            max_digit = max(vals)
        else:
        #If text happens to be the first element of data set, set max_digit to zero
            max_digit = 0
        vals=[]
        formatted_rec.append(final_data %(max_digit, each_val))
    else:
        vals.append(each_val)

for each_rec in formatted_rec:
    print each_rec
```

Output:

```
0,02-sep-2016, blah blah, blah, 83838338
6,02-sep-2016, blah blah, blah, 83838338
3,03-Aug-2000, blah, 300033
```